# try & if statement in while loop

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop, jupyter-notebook, try-catch

I would like to build a function in which if the entered integer is between 1 and 10, return the result.

Here is my code:

```
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input("Enter a number (1-10): "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Wrong input")            
    else:
        if 1 <= num <= 10:
            break
        else:
            print("Wrong input")
            continue
```

When you enter an integer, the `break` does not function properly and it seems to go into a definite loop.  Is it wrong to incorporate `if` statement into `else`?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue you describe. When I run the code you show, it works as I'd expect. Can you show an example series of inputs that produce incorrect results? The only issue I see is that `10` is not accepted.

Comment: @Blckknght, thank you for your prompt reply.  It made me feel a little easier. Maybe it has to do with the fact I am running it on Jupyter notebook.  It works fine as long as an error value is entered but once I enter an integer, it shows   In [*]  on the left side of the cell and stops showing output.

And yes, I need ot change num 9 to 10, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of break, print num.

```py
isBetweenOneAndTen = True

while isBetweenOneAndTen == True:
    try:
        num = int(input("Enter a number (1-10): "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Wrong input")            
    else:
        if 1 <= num <= 9:
            print(num)
            isBetweenOneAndTen = False

        else:
            print("Wrong input")
            continue
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I suppose the suggested change would make it a real inifinite loop which is not my initial intention.  I want to escape the while loop once an integer 1 to 10 is entered. (and sorry, it needs to be ```else: if 1 <= num <= 10``` in the code.)

Comment: Ok, I am sorry. You can create a variable and instead of while True you can write while this variable is True. When the number is between one an ten just set  the variable to False. It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks again for suggeting a solution. Yes I see that should be another option, too, though it also stopped on my end. But it helped me conclude it was not a problem with the code but with my environment.